# Display input array elements in a new line

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have an issue, where we would like to display the elements of an array in a new line.below is my code

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" data-ng-model="arrColumnNames" ng-list="&#10;" ng-trim="false"  required
    name="arrColumnNames" required minlength="0"
    placeholder=""
    class="form-control"></textarea>

<textarea id="test" class="form-control"  style="margin-top:2%; width: 60%;" rows="10" >
Resulting definition:<![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Scols >
<scol>{{arrColumnNames}}</scol>
</Scols>
]]>
</textarea>
```

In the above code,in the first input text area(with textarea class="form-control"), the user enters the array elements. I wanted those user entered array elements to be displayed in the textarea with id="test".When the array is displayed in the textarea with id="test" it is getting displayed horizontally,for eg. if the user inputs three elements in the input text area(with textarea class="form-control") , then the textarea with id="test" is displaying the below

```
<scol>["s1","s2","s3"]</scol>
```

I want to know how to display the elements like below.

Expected output

```
<scol>s1</scol>
<scol>s2</scol>
<scol>s3</scol>
```

Is there any way to display the elements of the array in the above format. Any help on hte above is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: While typing in textArea how does user differentiate between array elements? From above, is this ["s1","s2","s3"] what user typed in textarea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ng-repeat`

```
<Scols>
    <scol ng-repeat="values in arrColumnNames">{{values}}</scol>
</Scols>
```

Check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yzghqkv/)

Comment: I guess you have not understood my requirement. in the first input text area(with textarea class="form-control"), the user enters the array elements. I wanted those user entered array elements to be displayed in the textarea with id="test" . As specified above, its currently getting displayed as <scol>["s1","s2","s3"]</scol>. But wanted it to display it as <scol>s1</scol>
<scol>s2</scol>
<scol>s3</scol> Hope the requirement is clear now.

Comment: @vr3w3c9 I guess you updated the ques, check this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzo96ryj/  . U need to pass valid json array (`["s1","s2","s3"]`) to make it work

Comment: Thanks for the update. But Still i dont understand what ur fiddle code is doing. I dont see any relevance to the query that I have asked. Im not able to view any data in  < Scols>
    <scol ng-repeat="values in array">{{values}} <br>  </scol>
</Scols>
Even after inserting values in Todo textarea

Comment: pass a valid array in text box, since ng-repeat works only on arrays, for ex: ["s1","s2","s3"]